# Расчет угла по географическим координатам

Tags: java, математика, геометрия, координаты

Пытаюсь определить углы по географическим координатам
 и делаю это так:

```
double dLat = yLat - xLat;
double dLng = yLng - xLng;
double angle = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(dLng, dLat));
if (angle < 0) angle += 360;
```

и вроде все получается, но определяется не угол, а азимут, т.е если координаты (все прямо) идут с **востока на запад** то угол равен <strike>90</strike> **270** градусов, а по факту должен быть равен 180 (ибо развернутый угол).

**Есть идеи?**

Upd: вроде даже понял как это называется: *Как азимут перевести в тригонометрический угол? или что-то подобное.*

Получается так: Прямая дорога, и когда едешь в сторону запада, то угол будет равен 270 градусов, НО дорога же **прямая**, и поэтому **угол**, насколько я понимаю должен быть **развернутым (180 градусов).**

Comment: Взять учебник по сферической геометрии и не применять не пойми какие формулы...

Comment: А что такое угол для двух точек?

Comment: @AlexeyTen тут третья точка подразумевается, это точка в которой расположен наблюдатель =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ даже сферический наблюдатель в вакууме должен иметь координаты :)

Comment: @AlexeyTen в геодезических задачах так часто бывает. Вы знаете ваше местоположение, широту и долготу точки, куда вы плывете сейчас и широту и долготу точки, на которую вы хотите изменить курс.

Comment: @AlexeyTen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42258637/how-to-know-the-angle-between-two-points

Comment: Ну таки очень похоже на азимут

Comment: Для задания угла нужно три точки или другие дополнительные данные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попытаемся разобраться в земных сферах.

---

**Координаты и расстояния.**

Точка на поверхности Земли задаётся географической широтой **p** и географической долготой **q**.
Радиус Земли **R=6400 км.**

Сферические координаты **{R, p, q}** этой точки можно перевести в декартовы по формулам

[image: Вычисление декартовых координат]

Если имеется пара точек **A={R,p,q} и B{R,s,t}**, то расстояние между ними по прямой равно

[image: Расстояние по прямой]

Рассматривая окружность, проходящую через центр Земли, нетрудно получить формулы

[image: Угол земной дуги]
для угла (азимута) между этими точками по отношению к центру Земли.

Расстояние по Земле между точками A и B равно **cR**.

Это значит, что вычислять расстояния между объектами по их географическим координатам можно по  формуле

[image: Расстояние между объектами по их географическим координатам]

---

**Сферические треугольники**

Пусть задан сферический треугольник ABC со сферическими "сторонами" **a,b,c**.
Сторона **c** уже найдена, а для вычисления двух других сторон требуется только третья точка.

Угол ACB сферического треугольника ABC можно определить через формулу косинусов:

[image: Угол сферического треугольника]

Answer (score 0):

Вы утверждаете, что у вас получается азимут, почему тогда для 180 градусов тригонометрического угла у вас идет 90 градусов, по идее должно 270 быть (если не прав - поправьте). Если вас конкретно интересует, как перевести угол азимута в тригонометрический угол, могу предложить следующее: (360 - угол азимута + 90) mod 360.

Comment: Но ведь нельзя к географическим координатам применять формулу для плоскости. Ведь хотя бы то соображение, что один градус долготы имеет разную длину в зависимости от широты, должно пояснить, что ерунда получается.

Comment: @Mikhailo
Да, нельзя. Но вы путаете градусы - когда мы записываем положение, т.е. координаты, и азимут, ну или проще "курс" - угол между направлением на север и интересующим нас объектом. Начало отсчета у них отличается на 90 градусов, а также направлением. Насколько я понял вопрос автора, его интересовало как угол азимута перевести в привычное значение тригонометрическое значение угла.

Comment: не получается таким образом. Допустим если на север азимут направлен, а разницы в координатах почти нет, то показывает 180, а на север 90, юг - 270, несмотря на то что дорога прямая, а показывает 270, хотя должен 180 прямая дорога же развенутый угол, ведь?

Comment: Уточнил вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.atan2(dLng, dLat);
```

Эта функция переводит аргументы из [декартовых](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82) координат в [полярные](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82)

и  имеет значение в диапазоне от `-Math.PI` до `+Math.PI`

```
if (angle < 0) angle += 360;
```

а тут вы с ними как с градусами обращаетесь

Comment: Но ведь нельзя к географическим координатам применять формулу для плоскости. Ведь хотя бы то соображение, что один градус долготы имеет разную длину в зависимости от широты, должно пояснить, что ерунда получается.

Comment: @Mikhailo это смотря в какой проекции

Comment: @Mikhailo https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: @Mikhailo https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: Это я немного ошибся, надо было переводить в градусы.